# What's the correct word for "the state of being a vassal"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example,

> The knight was a vassal in the service of a baron.

What is the state of him being/not being a vassal, i.e.

> The vassal-ship of the knight dictated that he serve the baron.

What's the correct word to replace "vassal-ship"? Or is that bad grammar, and I shouldn't even need to use that word?

Comment: ***Vassalage*** :  the state of being a vassal. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vassalage - vassalage (n.)
c. 1300, from Old French vassalage, vasselage "the service of a vassal," from vassal. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vassalage

Comment: Looks like I was googling "to be a vassal", not "the state of being a vassal".

Comment: A similar word is to vacillate.

Comment: @Quentin ... no? Completely different meaning.

Comment: But it sounds similar.

Comment: @Quentin 1. I doubt it's from the same root. 2. Yeah, but it still has no bearing on "vassal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Josh pointed out, *Vassalage* is what you're looking for.

Vassalage via [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vassalage)

> 1. A position of subordination or submission (as to a political power)
> 2. The state of being a vassal
> 3. The homage, fealty, or due from a vassal

Comment: Josh doubtless put the word in a 'comment' because OP's research should have turned it up. Piggybacking such as this is detrimental to the site's credibility.

Comment: I disagree. OP perhaps should have done more research, but he asked a question and this is a question and answer forum. Josh's response was a direct answer to OP's question, and belongs in the answer section.

Comment: The polite practice is to promote someone else's answer given in a 'comment' for a reason they themselves have to a Community Wiki, rather than piggyback (there is a more formal term).

Answer (score 1):

Consider **allegeance**, as in "the allegeance of the knight to the king".

> Definition: the obligation of a feudal vassal to his liege lord; the
> loyalty of a subject to his or her sovereign.
>
> Example: *Vassals in the Middle ages were those who held the land, called a fief, and owed service and allegiance to the lord who granted them that land.  The vassal was usually a knight or a baron, but could also be a member of the clergy or a trusted member of nobility.  Vassals in the Middle Ages were an integral part of feudalism, which was the system of government throughout Europe in the Middle Ages*.

Read ["Rights and Responsibilities in Medieval Europe"](http://lordsknightsserfs.weebly.com/vassalsknights.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **fealty**:

From [Oxford Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fealty)

> mass noun
>
> historical
>
> 1A feudal tenant's or vassal's sworn loyalty to a lord.
>
> ‘they owed fealty to the Earl rather than the King’
>
> 1.1 Formal acknowledgement of loyalty to a lord.
>
> ‘a property for which she did fealty’

So your example would become:

> The knight owed **fealty** to the baron.